ReferenceError ?(<anonymous>) Ongoing Level: Error Unhandled shadowDOMUnlocker is not defined
I am getting below two errors logged in sentry happening on the production level and not in local for Angular app. unable to identify the root cause of it. Any idea?
exception:
1. shadowDOMUnlocker is not defined ReferenceError ?(<anonymous>)

2. toscaAlertAlerter is not defined ReferenceError ?(<anonymous>)

navigation :
{

from:

"/?type=saml2LoginFail&code=123&message=mockIssue&useSeamlessSSO=false&logoRect=https://example.com/s3/mock_logo_rect.png&logoSquare=https://example.com/s3/mock_logo_square.png&clientName=MockClient",

to:

"/?type=saml2LoginFail&code=123&message=mockIssue&useSeamlessSSO=false&logoRect=https:%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fs3%2Fmock_logo_rect.png&logoSquare=https:%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fs3%2Fmock_logo_square.png&clientName=MockClient"
}
PackageJSON for ref:
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular-slider/ngx-slider": "^2.0.4",
    "@angular/animations": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^14.0.0",
    "@aws-sdk/client-quicksight": "^3.565.0",
    "@kolkov/angular-editor": "^2.0.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^9.1.0",
    "@sentry/angular": "^7.28.1",
    "@sentry/tracing": "^7.28.1",
    "@sgratzl/chartjs-chart-boxplot": "^3.9.0",
    "amazon-quicksight-embedding-sdk": "^2.0.3",
    "chart.js": "^3.5.1",
    "dayjs": "^1.10.7",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "lz-string": "^1.4.4",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "ng-circle-progress": "^1.6.0",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^10.0.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^3.0.0-rc.5",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.7.1",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.0.0",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.9.32",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.41",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.6.4",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.5.0"
  }
   



Any more context what shadowDOMUnlocker and toscaAlertAlerter might be?

no idea literally. No further context. It mainly happens on login page

Any third party library in use for alerts?

Added package JSON info

It's also possible that these errors come from browser extensions and have nothing to do with your app

These errors are very likely caused by 3rd party browser extensions that inject scripts and expect something to be present that is not. Sentry tries to filter out known browser extension errors but it's a never ending cat & mouse game and sometimes not trivial to avoid false positives/negatives.
You have a couple of options to ignore these errors in Sentry:

Configure the ignoreErrors option in your SDK config
Filter on the error message in the Sentry UI's Inbound Filters
Using the (relatively new) thirdPartyErrorFilterIntegration. For this to work you need to add a bundler (likely webpack) plugin which requires you to use a custom Angular builder instead of the default config.

You also might want to look at the general filtering guide for additional options.
